# Alternatives to large horizontally scrolling views in Android

Tags: android, canvas, scroll

I am writing a DAW-style app and need to implement the side-scrolling timeline common in such programs. In other words it should appear to the user as though they are scrolling through a very large bitmap, several of them actually for the different tracks, seamlessly. Obviously I will have memory issues if I do it with a single very large horizontally-scrolling View, but that needs to be the effect the user sees. Right now I have a custom View for each track and drawing the wave into its Canvas.

I have thought of constructing three Views, left, active and right, and simply swapping out new data when the left or right one is scrolled to in time to be ready for the next screenfull. I think something along these lines is going to be the final solution, but I am not sure what would be the best way to implement it. Should I run a service in the background that watches for and updates the offscreen views, would that be the best way to accomplish this? I haven't used services before. Or is there a more direct way of doing it, attaching some code to the view to execute automatically?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.